# How to make non-blocking ReadLineAsync() to run concurrently in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, nonblocking

How can we read file lines using non-blocking IO concurrently?

A straightforward use of async await such that presented in `BiggestLineSequential` results in a sequential execution:

```
static async Task<string> BiggestLineSequential(String filename) {
    string longestLine = "";
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename)) {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                if (line != null && line.Length > longestLine.Length)
                {
                    longestLine = line;
                }
            }
        }
        return longestLine;
}
```

In this case, the call to `await reader.ReadLineAsync();` only proceeds  when the `Task` returned by  `ReadLineAsync()` completes. Thus, the next line will only be read when the previous one is already read from the file.

To achieve concurrent lines reads I tried the following approach:

```
static string BiggestLineConcurrent(String filename) {
      List<Task<string>> taskList = new List<Task<string>>();
      using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
      {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                  taskList.Add(reader.ReadLineAsync());
            }
      }

      string longestLine = "";
      foreach(Task<string> tsk in taskList)
      {
            string line = tsk.Result;
            if (line != null && line.Length > longestLine.Length)
            {
                  longestLine = line;
            }
      }

      return longestLine;
}
```

In this case, all the non-blocking IO operations are supposed to run concurrently instead of sequentially like is shown in the first example. All tasks are started and stored in a list, and then while the results become available, the processing continues.

However, the `BiggestLineConcurrent`  throws an `InvalidOperationException` with the message "*The stream is currently in use by a previous operation on the stream.*" in the line `while (!reader.EndOfStream)`.

Is there any way in .NET to read lines concurrently using non-blocking IO without explicit use of new threads or auxiliary thread-pool mechanisms?

Comment: If you can point to any system where it is possible to read lines of unknown length in parallel we can help you with porting that code to language of your choice. I personally don't expect one exists so... (Side note: consider tagging the question with language - possibly C#)

Comment: Why exactly do you need this? Also personally I would try something like `File.ReadLines(...).AsParallel().Max();` and see if the speed is enough.

Comment: That's not possible.  Multiple reasons why this doesn't make sense.  StreamReader only knows where to start reading the next line when it has finished reading the previous.  And there is no possible speedup, you have only one disk drive.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? This simple calculation won't benefit from parallelization and trying to use multiple streams is worse than what `File.ReadLines` or `File.ReadLinesAsync` would do. The OS is already reading the data as fast as possible. You could use `System.Linq.Async`'s `Max` to find the maximum length without blocking eg `var max=await File.ReadLinesAsync().Max(l=>l.Length);`. Or you can use LINQ's Max for faster calculation with blocking `File.ReadLines().Max(l=>l.Length)`. In both cases the maximum is calculated as the data is read

Answer (score 0):

You can't read multiple times from a stream at the same time, nor do I understand how it would make sense to do so. The stream only has one set of properties regarding its current position etc., so you would in effect have a concurrency clash.

Instead you could begin reading from multiple places using multiple streams.

```cs
static string BiggestLineConcurrent(String filename)
{
    var maxDOP = Environment.ProcessorCount;
    var fileLength = new FileInfo(filename).Length
    var tasks = Partitioner.Create(0, fileLength - 1)
        .GetPartitions(fileLength / maxDOP + 1)
        .Select(t => ReadData(filename, t.Item1, t.Item2));
    var longests = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return longests.MaxBy(l => l.Length);

    
    async Task<string> ReadData(string filename2, long from, long to)
    {
        var longest = "";
        using var stream = new FileStream(filename2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        stream.Position = from;
        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string line;
        try
        {
             while ((line = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
             {
                 if (longest.Length < line.Length)
                    longest = line;
                if (stream.Position > to)
                    stream.Close();
            }
         }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        { \\
        }
        return line;
     }
}
```

You need to close the stream when it gets to the end point of the partition, and then because the `StreamReader` can throw because of that you need to swallow that exception.

Your other alternative is to use some kind of [`PartialStream`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60592147/14868997).

Comment: Instead of messing around with multiple streams, just open a single file handle with `File.OpenHandle` and use multiple calls to `RandomAccess.ReadAsync` in parallel to read blocks of bytes, then decode those bytes.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to do that, sounds like you need PInvoke. You are welcome to make your own answer. This answer does have the upside that it can decode in parallel also, although your solution could also be written that way.

Comment: No need for PInvoke. [`File.OpenHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openhandle) and [`RandomAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.randomaccess) have been available since .NET 6, precisely to support this kind of concurrent reading or writing from a file.